# Doctrine Circular reference

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have just install a symfony 4.3 project. I got this error everytime I run something in it

```
Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
```

Comment: I just used "symfony new --full s434a" to create a new project and it seems to work as expected.  I did have to run the command a few time.  Got http type errors but once I got a clean install then no problems.  How did you install your new project?

Comment: It was already an existing project, I just pull. Issue was because an internal Symfony issue. When you inject Repository class into a doctrine subscriber service.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Just for info, Symfony and Doctrine are two different things so this is not technically a Symfony issue.  Doctrine listeners are injected into the entity manager when the manager is created.  Doctrine repositories have a link to their entity manager.  So if you have repositories being injected into listeners then you will indeed end up with a circular reference.  There should be no need to inject repositories into a listener.

Comment: This is the issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29693